# import html mysql table to excel with php. Big numbers converts to exponential in excel file

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetch data from mysql table in html format and further it export to excel using php. Mysql table contains bigint `stud_id` like `201927341302805000` when I exported to excel it will display like `2.01927E+17`. All `stud_id` of tables will converted to same number as `2.01927E+17`.

Script used for export to excel:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

I want send  bigint number as it is when I exported mysql file to excel.

Comment: I think that's related with the Excel cell formatting, try changing it to text format and see if it helps

Comment: @Claudio i will check it but it not working. Bigint number is correct in mysql but when it will exported to excel it will converted into exponential format 2.01927E+17 same for all number

Comment: @smitapatil Excel has a limit when dealing with very large numbers. You need to convert the output you get from MySQL into String, and then write into excel

Comment: @Claudio plz tell me detail